# multiple autorenewable subscription for dynamic services

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, auto-renewable

I am working on an iOS app, where a user can purchase a monthly auto renewable subscription for the consultation, provided by a doctor. In my app, a user can also purchase such subscription for multiple doctors at the same time. Moreover, doctors are not pre-defined, they keep onboarding to the app by independent signup and patient starts subscribing them on a monthly autonewable subscription basis.

I have two questions here:

1. Can I use payment gateway here or I need to go with IAP?
2. If I have to go with IAP? Does apple provide such model?

Thanks